# Bigquery union two arrays of different struct

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables

`v1
ARRAY<STRUCT<a int64>>`

and

`v2
ARRAY<STRUCT<a int64, b int64>>`

I want to write query which unions both tables using `union all` and for `v1` rows put nulls in place of `b` field. Any help is appreciated :)

I'm using standard SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT val.a, NULL AS b FROM UNNEST(arr1) val) arr
FROM `project.dataset.v1` 
UNION ALL 
SELECT arr2 AS arr
FROM `project.dataset.v2`
```

you can test, play with above using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.v1` AS (
  SELECT [STRUCT<a INT64>(1),STRUCT(2),STRUCT(3)] arr1
), `project.dataset.v2` AS (
  SELECT [STRUCT<a INT64, b INT64>(100, 1),STRUCT(100, 2),STRUCT(100, 3)] arr2
)
SELECT 
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT val.a, NULL AS b FROM UNNEST(arr1) val) arr
FROM `project.dataset.v1` 
UNION ALL 
SELECT arr2 AS arr
FROM `project.dataset.v2`
```

with result as

```
Row arr.a   arr.b    
1   1       null     
    2       null     
    3       null     
2   100     1    
    100     2    
    100     3
```